# Running specific profile from command line in Specflow C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, specflow

I've been working quite a lot with PHP Behat and I'm trying to emulate the same thing in C# with specflow. One of the issues I'm running into is that my I want to use the same test for multiple (50+)websites, basically pushing an argument in command line and telling it which website to go to.
In Behat I'd use Behat.yml, set multiple profiles with a format similar to this:

websiteA:
url: whatever.com
websiteB:
url: blabla.com

And then specify in command line the profile I want "behat -p websiteA" and based on that I have a function that uses the url for my specific website.

I'm pretty new to everything C# and specflow so I am wondering how could I have this solution in specflow. So far I managed to create a basic scenario that I run with "dotnet test" in command line.

Also I'm using selenium.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include how you run SpecFlow tests from the command line?

Comment: Have you considered using environment variables? - Code your test to read from the environment variables, then, in your command line set your variable then kick off dotnet test?  e.g. command line: `Set "MyVar_GoHere=WebsiteA" && dotnet test ...`

Comment: @gregBurghardt at the moment I'm running simply with "dotnet test" in command line, as mentioned in the post.\

Comment: @RichEdwards I'm trying more of a hardcoded in framework approach. I've been noticing that in C# there a configuration files and Specflow has some form of profiles. but I don't want to create a file for every single website, since I have a lot.

Comment: Hi Alex, there's an approach to use the build configurations name as an input variable that drives a pre-build configuration file. We used it to split our tests across different environments and get differ variables like accounts ans passwords. That sound something you want an answer on? -  no worries it for I just won't post if it's not right for you :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards that sounds pretty promising as a solution to my problem. If you could post it here, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying multiple ways at the moment in order to see which is easiest to approach and maintain in time.

Comment: I'll type an answer anyway - but is this what you were after? `dotnet test -s MySettings.runsettings`  - i've not used it but details are in profle pages of the specflow runner : https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Profiles.html#default-profile

Comment: @richedwards I've been looking into that but I would have to have multiple files or somehow multiple sets of configurations inside a single file and then call them as an argument. Which I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite the solution you've requested (i.e. not using specflow profiles) but as a general c# approach to toggling websites you can use the build configuration options.

In Build > Configuration Manager you can create new profiles for each environment/URL. Expand out the Active solution configutations and you can create new:

[image: Build Configuration Manager]

You say you have 50 websites, and as this is just a driver, the same information can be controlled by editing your solution (.sln) file:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Demo|Any CPU = Demo|Any CPU
        Dev|Any CPU = Dev|Any CPU
        Prod|Any CPU = Prod|Any CPU
            *...etc*
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {C634C2D6-7FB9-4B47-923F-9E8634843928}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C634C2D6-7FB9-4B47-923F-9E8634843928}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C634C2D6-7FB9-4B47-923F-9E8634843928}.Demo|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Demo|Any CPU
          *...etc*
```

The GUID is a reference to the project in the solution. It's all copy+paste-able.

Once those are added you can create code to read and review the runtime settings to create/set variables as you need.

Our approach (and i'm sure there are others) was to create a powershell script which would take that Configuration name and build our settings file as a **pre-build event** for the project:
[image: pre-build settings]

You can see the input into the powershell is `$(ConfigurationName)`. The content of this scripts is limited by your imagination :-)

For us, this was especially useful as we had to get passwords and other API keys from our secret manager per environment. It would create a local .json file with everything we needed to run our tests. The framework would then only ever need to know about a single file and it worked just as well running in CI pipes.

Finally - when it comes to running `dotnet test`, you use `-c` and pass it the build you want ([options are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test)):

> `-c|--configuration <CONFIGURATION>`
>
> Defines the build configuration. The default value is Debug, but your
> project's configuration could override this default SDK setting.